# Получение значения нажатого элемента

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Можно ли как-нибудь получить значение элемента на который я нажал? (при нажатии на блок со значением 1 выводило 1, 2-2, 3-3 и тд).

HTML

```
            <div onclick=addNum() class="key">1</div>
            <div onclick=addNum() class="key">2</div>
            <div onclick=addNum() class="key">3</div>
            <div onclick=addNum() class="key">4</div>
```

JS

```
function addNum(){
alert(ЭтотЭлемент.value);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div onclick="addNum(this)" class="key">1</div>

function addNum(el) {
  alert(el.textContent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function addNum(el) {
  alert(el.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div onclick=addNum(this) class="key">1</div>
<div onclick=addNum(this) class="key">2</div>
<div onclick=addNum(this) class="key">3</div>
<div onclick=addNum(this) class="key">4</div>
```

Можно через слушателей:

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
divs.forEach(div => { 
    div.addEventListener('click', () => addNum(div));
});

function addNum(el) {
  alert(el.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="key">1</div>
<div class="key">2</div>
<div class="key">3</div>
<div class="key">4</div>
```